# Executing JAR file within JFrame

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jar

Well I have a .jar file of my project which I want to use inside a tab in tabbed view in Java. I am using Eclipse IDE. Is there any way to do it? Or I have to import all Java files one by one in the project? Importing all Java files will slow down the performance of my app.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "...I want to use inside a tab..." ? Do you mean when you open the tab then the jar is loaded and executed.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just add the jar to your classpath and you can use any classes inside it.

Comment: I mean when I select that particular tab, I want that .jar application to run within that tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any `Component` to a [`JTabbedPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html), but the `.jar` file has to offer a way to create that `Component`. Look in the jar's public API for a constructor or factory method that does this. If there's no public API, you can try [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), but there's no guarantee it'll work.

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounds lame, but where exactly can I look for the .jar's public API? :(

Comment: No apology needed :-) The `javadoc` is the best place to start, followed by any existing sample code. If all else fails, try `javap` on the JAR manifest's `Main-Class`.

Comment: Thanks @Catalina Island. The problem is solved :)